# What mathematical function do I2C falling edges follow, and why?

Tags: i2c

Consider any standard I2C communication : the falling edges, either on SDA or on SCL, will take a certain amount of time to complete.

- What mathematical function do these falling edges follow?
- Why do they follow this function, from an electronic point of view?

Comment: The behave like open drain signals. You can google them. Basically, it's either input-like state or pulled through the transistor to the ground

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Actually not at all. I just got curious.

Comment: freshman and sophomore EE classes cover the basics.  Understand the reality is there are a number of components which you could model, but each of the components and thus combined can be modelled. Real world the exact numbers vary, the resistors and caps and etc are not built to exact values with infinite precision, plus your pcb which is its own huge model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the falling edge of an I2C line the trace capacitance is discharged through the low side FET. The FET has a constant gate-source voltage.
This results in the current first beeing almost constant and leveling down to a constant resistance discharge, when the line voltage (which is \$V_{DS}\$) drops below \$V_{GS}-V_{th} \$.

So in the constant current discharge segment the voltage falls linearily and then levels off to the typical RC discharge curve.

But in reality you will have difficulties seeing such a voltage waveform, because the discharge happens almost instantly. Assume a trace capacitance \$C_t\$ of 5 pF. With an \$R_{DS}\$ of \$1~\Omega\$ the RC constant is in the order of 5ps. With lower \$R_{DS}\$ it obviously is even faster.

If you want to be even more precise you might want to add the effect of the pullup resistor, which will still be present. This will result in a minor DC offset.

Comment: What are V_GS, V_th and R_DS ?

Comment: Specifications of the driving MOSFET

Comment: V_GS is the gate-source voltage of the FET, so bascially the controll voltage. V_th is the threshold voltage and is a parameter describing, at which point the FET becomes conductive. R_DS is the drain-source resistance, which is the resistance which discharges the trace. For descrete FETs you can find these values in the datasheet, but typically you won't find them for the FETs integrated in bus driver ICs.

Comment: Ok. I think you meant 5ps (instead of 50ps) for the RC constant. Last question, why do the pullup resistors cause a DC offset in the falling edge curve ? Is it a positive or negative offset ?

Comment: You are obviously right, 5ps is correct. In the "end-phase" the mosfet act like a small resistor and forms a voltage divider with the pullup. This results in a tiny positive offset.

Answer (score 2):

Think about the structure of an I2C bus line: it is pulled up to the supply (usually 5 or 3.3V) and it's pulled down by the I2C driver in the chip. Also there is some internal capacitance (wires, traces and so on).

In it's simplest form the falling edge is simply an open drain driver: so it will be driven down with some transistor (probably a MOSFET); you will have a transient from VCC to almost ground limited by the internal resistance of the transistor (less than one ohm, usually). Technically still an exponential since you are discharging the parasitic line capacitor but quite fast.

More 'enhanced' drivers have controlled slew rate to reduce emission (especially for low power ICs in slow I2C buses). The shape depends on the internal circuit but it's mostly a linear ramp, always from VCC to ground. The speed (slope) is determined by the IC manufacturer and sometime it is programmable (often you can disable the slew limiter for fast I2C).

The rising edge instead is simply the parasitic line capacitor recharging thru the pullup resistor, so it's a pure exponential. *There is* an exception for the clock line in high speed I2C but it's quite rare.

Comment: "rate limited" [i.e. dV/dt] -- yes this is the essential answer to the question IMO

Comment: AFAIK the I2C standard (at least the classic one) doesn't specify a wave shape but only the reference levels and timings… so it is decided by the IC manufacturer

Comment: Yes, there is a max and min* fall time. To me this gives reason to expect the likelyhood of something more than a basic open-drain in an mcu or bus-expander chip.   [* fast modes only]

Comment: "There is an exception for the clock line in high speed I2C" > Could you elaborate on that, or link to some resource about it ?

Comment: High speed has a rise accelerator for the clock on the master. Is on… the I2C specifications. Look for UM10204

Comment: Thanks for this piece of information

Answer (score 1):

> What mathematical function do these falling edges follow ?

That's not defined. Typically, something like a band-limited rectangle (thus, slight ringing) overlaid with a capacitive charge curve (\$1-e^{-\alpha t}\$) overlaid with the dynamic properties of the driver IC.

> Why do they follow this function, from an electronic point of vue?

So, you need to think about this the other way around. Understand how open-drain voltage signals with slightly capacitive loads look like, and you can start modelling the function.

Comment: "That's not defined" > Do you mean that it depends on the hardware implementation of the I2C bus ? Also, what do you mean by "overlaid" ?

Comment: It's not defined by the standard. It depends on the hardware and the length of the bus and the other devices attached to the bus and the pull up mechanism / impedance.

Comment: Alright. What about "overlaid" ? Do you mean that the resulting function would be the sum of the three functions you mention ? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "band-limited rectangle" and "ringing"

Comment: no, I mean the effects combine, to form your observed waveform. If you're not familiar with the terms "band-limited", but want to describe signals, you might be missing a bit of basic signal theory, I'm afraid.